# Audio not playing under scenekit

Tags: ios, swift, audio, scenekit

How to play audio under scenekit?

```
let source = SCNAudioSource(fileNamed: "sample.mp3")
let action = SCNAction.playAudio(source!, waitForCompletion: true)
        
let scene = SCNScene()
self.scenekitView.scene = scene
scene.rootNode.runAction(action)  // no sound
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`source.load()` fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing 'let scene' to a var scene, then handle the rest in viewDidLoad as follows:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var SoundAction = SCNAction()
    var SoundNode = SCNNode()
    var scene = SCNScene()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Change this
        scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!

        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)

        let ship = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: true)!
        ship.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: 2, z: 0, duration: 1)))

        let audioSource = SCNAudioSource(named: "MenuWinner.caf")!
        audioSource.volume = 1.0
        SoundAction = SCNAction.playAudio(audioSource, waitForCompletion: false)

        let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
        scnView.scene = scene
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
        scnView.showsStatistics = true
        scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
        scnView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    @objc
    func handleTap(_ gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(SoundNode)
        SoundNode.runAction(SoundAction)
    }
```